# How to create a backup branch from the original origin branch after a rebase?

Tags: git

I rebased a feature branch from origin/master

On feature branch:
`git rebase origin/master`

It worked. Now I need to push the changes. But it won't work unless I force push it.

What I want is to create a backup of the original feature branch locally before forcing it, just to have it in case. (I was advised to do so)

How can I do this?

The simplest solution that I see is to create another backup branch from the rebased one and then do a `git reset --hard HEAD@{x}` and I'll end up with a previous version of the branch(before rebase) and a rebased branch. But I am not sure if it's the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`origin/<feature-branch>` should still contain your original feature branch (from before you rebased). So checkout that branch and create a new branch from it.

For example:

```
git checkout origin/<feature-branch>
git checkout -b feature-branch-backup
```

Comment: I thought of this. But it won't create a branch on origin instead of locally?

Comment: Nope, just a new “normal” branch.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need is the Commit Id your feature branch used to point to. If `git rev-parse HEAD@{x}` returns a commit Id, then you can use the `HEAD@{x}` notation in place of any argument that accepts a commit id.

The easiest way I can think of is:

```
git branch feature_backup HEAD@{x}
```

This creates a new local branch at the commit specified by `HEAD@{x}` and does not affect your working directory.